# Regular expression for zero-width Unicode characters

Tags: regex, perl, text, unicode

I’m converting a table to a human-readable form, and I need to treat the content with zero-length Unicode characters “in a distinctive way”.

The only way to recognize them seems to be (even with Perl’s extensions!) to list all the possibilities “which get in the way” (what I found in my tables are CGJ, ZW [non]joiners, and r2l/l2r marks).  I tried to use Perl’s `\p{XPosixPrint}, but it fails:

```
perl -we "print(qq(\n)), print, print qq(\t), (chr hex) =~ /\p{XPosixPrint}/ for @ARGV" 034f 200c 200d 200e 200f

034f    1
200c    1
200d    1
200e    1
200f    1
```

Did I miss anything: is there a (combination of) `\p{…}` which would match zero-width Unicode characters (and only them)?

Comment: No, there is no such a class. Just use a character class with the code points you need to match. `[\x{200B}-\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]`, there are just four having "zero width" in the name.

Comment: It is trivial to look for “zero width” in the name — until the next Unicode update!  Moreover, as you can see in my question, **I list *five* different 0-width characters** — and this does not include `U+feff` (thanks for reminding me of this one!).  **Conclusion:** looking for the Unicode-name **is not enough…**

Comment: "until the next Unicode update" pertains to everything. "Not enough" - so what do you want? Make developers re-write the regex support in Perl?

Comment: Your “pertainsto everything” is patently wrong.  For example, it is not applicable to ``s/\w/A/g` — **because there is a documented interface** to reach this info, Perl/etc. are going to be “eventually updated” to track the new Unicode rules.  And this is **what I want**: locate a documented interface — if it exists.  (Was not this unclear from the original question?  Please point this out so I can improve it, thanks…)

Comment: Are you still involved in perl development? I like the idea of adding a class for it...

Comment: Heh, [this list of commits](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3APerl%2Fperl5+ilya&type=commits) might be interesting before you comment on what Ilya is trying to do. :)

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no character property in the Unicode standard specifically for that purpose, but a good approximation of what you’re after may be `Default_Ignorable_Code_Point`, as defined in the [DerivedCoreProperties.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/DerivedCoreProperties.txt) data file. This property set includes:

- Most format control characters that regularly do not have a glyphic appearance of their own (such as Zero Width Space, the join controls, and the bidirectional controls)
- Most invisible combining marks (such as CGJ and variation selectors)
- Miscellaneous characters like the Hangul jamo fillers, which typically have neither glyph nor advance width
- Ranges of currently unassigned code points that are informally reserved for future additions of similar nature

Being zero-width is not a defined concept in the Unicode standard, so you will likely still need to make some adjustments to the set of characters depending on your exact needs. For example, the “interlinear annotation” format controls (U+FFF9..U+FFFB) are deliberately excluded from the `Default_Ignorable_Code_Point` property despite fitting your criteria for zero-width characters quite well.

The purpose of `Default_Ignorable_Code_Point` is to mark characters that, if not supported, should be discarded entirely when rendering text instead of being substituted with a placeholder glyph (such as a box or a question mark) as would be common practice for most other characters. Naturally this includes a lot of characters that are meant to be invisible in the first place.

However, some of these invisible characters are really important for parsing the structure of the text they appear in. If they’re not properly supported it is actually best practice to represent them with a visible placeholder so that the reader at least knows that something went wrong on their end. This is why characters like the aforementioned interlinear annotation controls are explicitly not default-ignorable. The C0 and C1 controls (`gc=Cc`, i.e. U+0000..U+001F and U+007F..U+009F) are not default-ignorable for the same reason.

There are other edge cases that cannot be resolved easily. For example, whether or not U+1D159 MUSICAL SYMBOL NULL NOTEHEAD is invisible and zero-width depends entirely on the whims of the font currently being used to display it. There also exist so-called “invisible stackers” (`Indic_Syllabic_Category=Invisible_Stacker`) in many writing systems which are zero-width combining marks that modify the appearance of adjacent characters without being visible themselves *except* when they’re being used in an invalid or incomplete sequence, in which case they may or may not show up depending on the font and the text renderer. None of these characters are default-ignorable.

If your goal is to catch 100% of characters that “get in the way” according to your personal criteria, you will have to keep a custom list of characters and be ready to update it with every new Unicode release. If 99% is good enough, I’d recommend simply relying on the `Default_Ignorable_Code_Point` property with a few hard-coded additions like the interlinear annotation stuff and the C0 and C1 sets. Most of these characters discussed here are incredibly obscure and unlikely to ever show up in normal text data.

Comment: Wow!  This exceedd all expectations! — Thanks!  (Looking again through my tables with my current visualizers, I found *yet another border case* — and it is even in `Latin-1`!  It is `U+00ad`=`SOFT HYPHEN`.)

Comment: I read what you wrote as that “in this context” **people could not find a way to describe *intent* with fine enough granularity**.  A pity!  (In my applications, I have very short “chunks of text” — like “AI’s tokens” — and their repertoire needs to be inspected by a human.  Actually, they are bindings of keys on a keyboard; for example, [as one could have guessed] my keyboard can emit “ — ” on a certain key.  It is unwildy to visualize this as `U+2009 U+2014 U+2009` — so I currently visualize as `⟬⍽—⍽⟭`.  This is lossy — e.g., all “funny spaces” merged into `⍽`, but “better than nothing”.)

Comment: Thinking about this more: there are TWO intents I may spell out explicitly: ***XYZ* there are situations where humans cannot tell whether the character is present or not**, with ***XYZ*** either **When used as intended**, or **Sometimes**..  (The second sense is close to “invisible”…)  For practical purposes this may be further refined to include “when used as the first/non-first character” and “standalone”.

Comment: Very interesting, what a knowledge of Unicode! I particularly appreciate the passage on invalid or incomplete sequences.

Answer (score 4):

The earlier answer focuses on the choice of characters to include, so I'm going to focus on how to match those characters if you choose to go with a custom list.

Using `[\x{200B}-\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]` as an example,

- You could [define your own class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode#User-Defined-Character-Properties).

  ```perl
  sub IsZW {
     state $IsZW =
        join "\n", map s/-/ /r, split /,/,
           "200B-200D,FEFF";

     $IsZW
  }

  /...\p{ IsZW }.../
  ```
- You could interpolate a subpattern.

  ```perl
  my $zw_char = qr/[\x{200B}-\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]/;

  /...$zw_char.../
  ```
- You could define a subpattern.

  ```perl
  /
     ...(?&zw_char)...

     (?(DEFINE)
        (?<zw_char> [\x{200B}-\x{200D}\x{FEFF}] )
     )
  /x
  ```

So, once you decide on the list of characters in which you are interested, there are plenty of options to make it easy to use.

Comment: Uh-oh! Things went far from my (botched!) initial attempt to define `\N{}`…

Answer (score 2):

See the earlier answer regarding the Default_Ignorable_Code_Point property. If that suits your needs, then you can use `\p{DI}` to reference the class defined by that property in Perl regex.

See https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.

Comment: Thanks!  (But I need to use this *ONCE* per a package.  So this is “the eternal dilemma” of **Should I use a shortcut — and then I need to explain it in a comment** vs. **Use a longer version anyway**…  ½–☹)